# Access USB or Serial in C#

Tags: c#, usb, serial-port

How do I send and receive via USB in C#? And what about Serial and LPT?

Comment: This is an old question. To tell you the truth, I can't even remember what I was trying to do. `:)` A two year old question. I was actually expecting a simple example of something that works. How to send bytes over usb.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Example of simple usb app [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/archive/2006/10/31/912422.aspx).

Use the serial port class, found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) for serial port.

Decent example of LPT [here](http://www.thaiio.com/prog-cgi/CshapeParallelPort.htm).

Comment: i think that this is a bit misleading as it is for HID usb not all usb ports

Comment: @Parhs, OP selected this as the answer to question. Doesn't sound like they were mislead.

Comment: Links are invalid

Comment: @fnc12, Only one link is missing and considering this was posted six years ago I am not surprised.

Comment: @Gabe, can you post an updated link, please?

Answer (score 4):

For accessing USB ports you can use [LibUsbDotNet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbdotnet/) library