# Can I use System.IO.Ports.SerialPort to read USB

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access USB or Serial in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594519/access-usb-or-serial-in-c-sharp)

Can I use System.IO.Ports.SerialPort to read USB smart card reader or I have to convert to RS-232 Serial COM Port?

How can I read send and read response from USB?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Ok. I will not include next time. I do this because I try to find similar question about c#.

Comment: You can find questions about C# by searching on the tag, or clicking [tag:C#].

Comment: @JohnSaunders I believe that the OP meant he had seen the convention used elsewhere - [C# Program to change Mouse settings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629167/c-sharp-program-to-change-mouse-settings), [How to get log in user's on local machine with the help of C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636976/how-to-get-log-in-users-on-local-machine-with-the-help-of-c), etc... even the dupe linked in the comments.